# Which is better for USD payment for Indians : Wire Transfer or Cheque?

Tags: india, check, wire-transfer, usd-us-dollar, inr-indian-rupee

I am about receive some reimbursement of ~1000 US dollars. I live in India, whose currency is INR. I have the option to receive the money in form or cheque or wire-transfer.
Which of the two mode of payments should I chose for maximum benefit ?

PS: by maximum benefit, I mean being charged least transaction charges and gaining highest amount in INR from USD.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you get this using Wire Transfer. The fees is slightly high, it should be in the range of USD 20 - 30. You would get the funds faster, about 3-5 days after the payment is initiated. The Fx conversion would be applied without your knowledge so you would have very little control over it.

If you are getting by paper cheque, it would take around 7 - 10 days for the mail to arrive. You would have to deposit this in local Bank, complete a form giving out the details as to why you received the cheque, along with a letter to request the cheque to be cashed ... Generally it takes around 25 days for the funds to get credited. As you would be speaking to someone in Bank, you can try and negotiate a better Fx rate, however for such amounts Bank will not go out of the way, so you may not know what rate gets applied, it would be the standard rate some 20 days later when the actual cheque gets processed. The fees are relatively less in the range of Rs 500 to Rs 1000.